# Replace space with underscore in string pickle

Tags: python, pandas, pickle

I have data in pickle format and inside the file is dictonary with several file names in the key which are like below

```
Key Type Size Value

22 NN_64_100_0.txt float 1 nan
```

The key has several names with the spaces in-between. I want to replace that with underscore like below.

```
 22_NN_64_100_0.txt
```

I tried this way like below:

```
with open('/data/record.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    data = pickle.load(f)    

    {data.replace(' ', '_'): v for k, v in data.items()}
```

But it didn't work

Can anyone help how to make it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Regex to replace several spaces into underscores

```py
import re

with open('/data/record.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    data = pickle.load(f)    
    {re.sub(r' ', '_', k): v for k, v in data.items()}
```

Tell me if its not okay for you...

Comment: TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object    this is error. Now the Type is dict.

Comment: @ML85 is the `data` in your code is a dict? then how can u apply string methods to a dict tho? i edited my code, check it and tell me if there's still any errors

Comment: No. still the spaces are there. But now there is no error.

Comment: where do u store that dictionary tho? the code is working for me tho...